# What's the best solution to replicate terraform repositories' structure?

Tags: repository, terraform, devops, cookiecutter

I'm looking for a solution to replicate my terraform repositories structure that is always identical

- config (dev/stg/prod - backend.tf + input.tfvars)
- tests/
- main.tf / variables.tf / outputs.tf
- Jenkinsfile / version / CHANGELOG / README / CONTRIBUTING

I'm looking for a solution to reproduce this structure over new repositories by running a command line such as [cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/README.html) for Python code, for example.

My goal is to avoid copy/paste from one repo to another, and reuse as much as I can a base already coded (having something good from a DevOps perspective)
I dont think cookie cutter supports terraform scripts and I dont know any other potential solution to reproduce terraform repos.

Comment: I'm not looking for a template for a tool that would reproduce the content of the template with only the need to change the main+ config inforamtions

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Terraspace](https://terraspace.cloud/). It builds Terraform projects to achieve DRY.

Here's a also blog article on it: [Introducing Terraspace: The Terraform Framework](https://blog.boltops.com/2020/08/22/introducing-terraspace-the-terraform-framework)

Comment: Awesome, I'll look into it to see if tht fits!

Comment: I tried terraspace and terragrunt, both looked nice for DRY but it wasn't letting me create a skeleton for terraform recipes. I couldn't have a Jenkinsfile already set up, the usual versioning/documentation files and create a the structure I wanted for the config.

Comment: So I finally created the template using cookiecutter https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/ 
I used created several variables such as component.name
So when I run cookie cutter it creates a terraform-{{cookiecutter.component_name}} folder with everything I need